# Apache Cordova dropbox-sdk-js

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm trying to print the number (array length) of files and folder of my dropbox cordova app folder, but I get this error message: "CANNOT READ PROPERTY LENGTH OF UNDEFINED"

My Code is here (Authentication works fine):

```
var dbx = new Dropbox({ clientId: DROPBOX_APP_KEY });

    dbx.authenticateWithCordova(
        function(accessToken) {              
            try {
                var objF = dbx.filesListFolder({path: ''}); 
                var arF = objF.entries;
                alert("SIZE: "+arF.length);
            }catch(errFL) {
                alert(errFL); 
            }
        },
        function() {        
            alert("FAILED!");
        }
    );
```

Dropbox sdk reference: https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js

What is the mistake?
Thanks in advance.

[SOLVED]
This is the solution that I've found:

```
var dbx = new Dropbox({ clientId: DROPBOX_APP_KEY });

    dbx.authenticateWithCordova(
        function(accessToken) {                             
            dbxt = new Dropbox({accessToken: accessToken});                
            try {
                dbxt.filesListFolder({path: ""}).then(function(response) {                       
                    var arResp = response.entries;
                    console.log("RESP: "+arResp.length);
                }); 
            }catch(errFL) {
                alert(errFL); 
            }
        },
        function() {        
            alert("FAILED!");
        }
    );
```

I think that the response of filesListFolder was derived from a deferred object. Now works. Thanks.

Comment: This means your `arF` object is `undefined` because `objF.entries` does not exist. Log your `objF` to the console and check which properties exist before trying to access them.

Comment: Solved, read edit post. Thanks.